# Cannot access a downloaded corpus in NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, python-3.6, corpus

I have downloaded the Russian NLTK corpus via `nltk.download`, but I cannot actually use it (Python 3.6.9, NLTK 3.5):

```
>>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru')
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru to
[nltk_data]     /home/morozov/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
True
>>> nltk.corpus.averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/morozov/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/lazyimport.py", line 122, in __getattr__
    return getattr(module, name)
AttributeError: module 'nltk.corpus' has no attribute 'averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru'
```

This seems to be some issue with this specific corpus, because the Brown corpus loads just fine:

```
>>> nltk.download('brown')
[nltk_data] Downloading package brown to /home/morozov/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package brown is already up-to-date!
True
>>> nltk.corpus.brown
<CategorizedTaggedCorpusReader in '.../corpora/brown' (not loaded yet)>
```

I've tried restarting my Python and re-downloading the corpus, nothing changes.

How do I get the Russian corpus to work?

Comment: maybe restart the kernal?

Comment: or try `from nltk.corpus import averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru`

Comment: @chitown88 Tried both, no effect.